# flask apache hosting - wsgi script shows loading but never returns

Tags: python, apache, flask

we are using mod-wsgi based hosting.
I have followed steps given in following URLs:

http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/deploying/mod_wsgi/

> Edit 1 : Newest URL :
>   http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/deploying/mod_wsgi/

Apache error log shows following message :

```
Loading WSGI script '/var/www/html/trunk/SPM/wsgi/flask.wsgi'
```

wsgi file looks like this :

```
import os
import sys
sys.stdout = sys.stderr
sys.path.insert(0,"/var/www/html/trunk/SPM")
from SPM.run import order as application
```

Folder tree structure looks like :

```
|-- __init__.py
|-- order_manager
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- order_manager.wsgi
|   |-- views.py
|-- run.py
|-- wsgi
|   `-- flask.wsgi
```

Can anyone help me to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may help to someone.
I fixed this issue by updating my `/etc/apache2/conf-enabled/ormgr.conf` file

```
<VirtualHost *:5000>

        ServerName 10.51.0.103

        WSGIDaemonProcess ormgr python-path=/var/www/html/trunk/SPM user=www-data group=www-data threads=5
        WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/trunk/project/wsgi/flask.wsgi

        <Directory /var/www/html/trunk/SPM/wsgi>
                WSGIProcessGroup ormgr
                WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
                #Require all granted
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```